# Open Google Maps API info window on page load

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I use the Google Maps & Google Places API the show my business data on a map. Actually the info window opens when i click the map marker but my goal is, that the infowindow opens on page load.

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

service.getDetails(request, function(place, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: place.geometry.location
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' +
            /* place.formatted_address +  '<br />' + */
            place.address_components[1].long_name + ' ' + place.address_components[0].long_name + '<br />' +
            place.address_components[6].long_name + ' ' + place.address_components[2].long_name + '<br />' +

            place.rating + place.user_ratings_total + '</div>');

            infowindow.open(map, this);
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should move the code for info window and marker  in main area

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: place.geometry.location
});

infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' +
            /* place.formatted_address +  '<br />' + */
            place.address_components[1].long_name + ' ' + place.address_components[0].long_name + '<br />' +
            place.address_components[6].long_name + ' ' + place.address_components[2].long_name + '<br />' +

            place.rating + place.user_ratings_total + '</div>');

infowindow.open(map, marker);
```